# SQL Server - Replace text in XML variable based on join

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

For my situation, I have similar XML to the following:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML

SET @MyXML = 
  '
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Cat</Nickname>
      <Name>Catherine</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Cat</Nickname>
      <Name>Joseph</Name>
    </Student>
  </Students>
  '

SELECT  T.Students.value('Nickname[1]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM    @MyXML.nodes('/Students/Student[Nickname = "Cat"]') T(Students)
JOIN    dbo.MyStudents CLASS ON T.Students.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)') = CLASS.StudentName
```

I want to update the records that get returned from this SELECT statement, replacing the Nickname with CLEARED.  So, if dbo.MyStudents has Joseph but not Catherine, the resulting @MyXML variable would be:

```
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Cat</Nickname>
      <Name>Catherine</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>CLEARED</Nickname>
      <Name>Joseph</Name>
    </Student>
  </Students>
```

Is there a way to do this by modifying the XML variable directly?  Or will I need to put the XML variable into a temp table and perform a .modify on the temp table?

So far, examples that I have found do not have the conditional update with .modify based on the join.

Answer (score 0):

Give this example a try. For more info see [Syntax of the FOR XML Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx).

```
-- sample @MyStudents table
declare @MyStudents table (StudentName varchar(90), NickName varchar(90));
insert @MyStudents values('Kent', '');
insert @MyStudents values('Robert', 'Bobby');
insert @MyStudents values('Lisa', 'LB');
insert @MyStudents values('Venkat', 'Big Cat');
insert @MyStudents values('Catherine', 'Cat');
insert @MyStudents values('Joseph', 'Joey');

DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = 
  '<Students>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Cat</Nickname>
      <Name>Catherine</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Joey</Nickname>
      <Name>Joseph</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Nickname>Bonzo</Nickname>
      <Name>Clifford</Name>
    </Student>
  </Students>'

select @MyXML = (
    select ( 
        select * from (
            -- set existing @MyStudent records to CLEARED
            select 
                'CLEARED' as NickName,
                T.Students.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Name
            from @MyXML.nodes('/Students/Student') T(Students)
            join @MyStudents CLASS ON T.Students.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)') = CLASS.StudentName
            union
            -- get students that aren't in @MyStudents table
            select 
                T.Students.value('Nickname[1]', 'varchar(20)') as NickName,
                T.Students.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Name
            from @MyXML.nodes('/Students/Student') T(Students)
            where not exists(select 1 from @MyStudents s where s.StudentName = T.Students.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(20)'))
    ) as t1
    for xml path('Student'), type)
for xml path('Students'), type)
```